# How to list all repositories?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

How can I list all available repositories in Mercurial in shell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mercurial repositories are just directories, so you list them with `ls` or the favourite directory listing tool of your choice. Or do you mean *find* all Mercurial repositories within a directory tree? If so `find` is your friend - look for directories containing `.hg` subdirectories:

```
 find . -name '.hg' -a -type d -prune
```

Comment: That's fine for *nix environments. On a Windows box you can do the following in the command prompt: `dir /s /b /AD .hg`